# Test for measuring change when you have same primary sampling units but different respondents in two waves of longitudinal survey

Tags: t-test, stata, panel-data, mcnemar-test

Which test should I apply for measuring change in proportions and means when I have same primary sampling units but different respondents in two waves of longitudinal survey? Should I apply McNemar's test for proportion and dependent-samples t test for means, or which test to study the difference between two waves? How can I do this in STATA?

Comment: What are "primary sampling units"?